# How to include command links in VS Code property descriptions in package.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Here's what I have tried using [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#command-uris) as a reference:

```
"myextension.myProperty": {
    "type": "string",
    "default": "",
    "markdownDescription": "This is my property description and I want to link this [command](command:editor.action.addCommentLine)!"
}
```

In the settings page, "command" doesn't show up as a link, just plain text.

Comment: Chances are this is simply not supported then. You could try opening a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

That was reported in [vscode issue 71295](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71295): "Support for command links in property descriptions".

And with [PR 100304](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/100304), it should be in VSCode v1.47, June 2020 "Permit command URIs in markdownDescription of extension setting"

> Without this PR:
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6726799/84792806-3edc7780-afec-11ea-980d-01f87d78a4c0.png]
>
> With this PR the word '**`here`**' becomes a **hyperlink** `(command:workbench,view.extensions)` that switches to Extensions view.